# How to enable video from /.attachments/?

Tags: azure-devops-wiki

I'm gonna enable a video on Azure Wiki page. This video is not public, so I have attached it to Azure Wiki page like a image and the file was uploaded to /.attachments/ folder. Is it possible to use it during creating a vide section?

I have tried the following options but it now working as expected - it looks, the source was not recognized (*Unable to play video*)

```
::: video
/.attachments/2022-08-03-13-58-19-ase-e9465a68-acd2-4f73-b11a-5cc52c96d8c5.mp4
:::
```

```
<video src="/.attachments/2022-08-03-13-58-19-ase-e9465a68-acd2-4f73-b11a-5cc52c96d8c5.mp4" width=400 controls></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the video as any other Wiki attachment like this:

- `[2022-08-03-13-58-19-ase-e9465a68-acd2-4f73-b11a-5cc52c96d8c5.mp4](/.attachments/2022-08-03-13-58-19-ase-e9465a68-acd2-4f73-b11a-5cc52c96d8c5.mp4)`

However, it's conceivable you may loose some of the intended video functionality when you treat it as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the video HTML block link following your wiki structure as follow

```
 <video src="https://dev.azure.com/{tenant}/{projectId}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoId}/Items?path=/.attachments/2022-08-03-13-58-19-ase-e9465a68-acd2-4f73-b11a-5cc52c96d8c5.mp4)" width=1000 controls>
</video>
```

In order to get the full link with the different **{tenant}/{projectId}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoId}**, just click on the link of your attachement and copy it removing everything after the "[fullURLlink].mp4/"